# table border not showing in generated pdf from abcpdf

Tags: c#, asp.net, abcpdf

Why are all the borders or similar are missing?
Such as table borders, hr tag, even form border is not working.

i am converting html context to pdf using abcpdf, and the html can be shown correctly on any browser with table borders, hr tag and so on.

i am using abcpdf7.

Comment: Checked this? http://jhottengineering.blogspot.co.at/2012/03/abcpdf-for-reporting-and-rendering.html

Comment: @Shoban my table borders are not showing at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time to close this discussion.
The result is that abcpdf seems only recognize the style of any table elements in that Style attribute. And also, if you set the border = 1px, it will not be shown on the pdf, but border with a larger pixel would show, ex. border = 3px.
This is how i solved my tricky problem after many trials.

Answer (score 0):

ABCpdf Version 7 was discontinued some years ago and is not compatible with IE8, IE9 or IE10. So this is the mmost likely reason that it's not working terribly well. See the feature chart here for details:

http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-8.htm

The current release of ABCpdf is Version 9.1. This is compatible with modern versions of IE and provides two different HTML rendering engines.

There is the MSHTML rendering engine which is broadly similar to IE and there is also the Gecko rendering engine which is broadly similar to Firefox 21.0. It's one line of code to switch between the two.

My replies may feature concepts based around ABCpdf. It's what I work on. It's what I know. :-)